# Add a Button and Add String Resources

Tags: android

I am new to the world of android app creation. I am going through the tutorials. I am having trouble adding strings and buttons. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: What kind of trouble do you have?:)

Comment: Adding buttons via xml or code?

Comment: I am just starting android app creating. I have tried adding strings but they do not change. Also I can't add any buttons. Maybe I am missing something obvious. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I must be missing something obvious. Any help welcome

Comment: please post some code or some error log. or else how do we know what string you are talking about ..

Comment: Hi. I am using Eclipse ADT. When I try to add a string it doesn't change the string name under resource elements. as for the other part about adding butons, i can't find the section to add any buttons. As I said, I am new to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to add a button lets say its "id" is "button1"

Declare it on main activity like below.

Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

// The is of yout button is found in ur xml file.

Comment: Hi. I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give your button an id in your XML file. If you want your button to have text it will tell you you need to give it a string name. You will find the strings xml file under res/values.

This is an example of how your button could look in your xml file

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1" />
```

In the java code you need to do something like this to declare it.

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Hi. I am using Eclipse ADT. When I try to add a string it doesn't change the string name under resource elements. as for the other part about adding butons, i can't find the section to add any buttons. As I said, I am new to this. Thanks

Comment: I recommend the New Boston tutorials on youtube they are amazing. How are you trying to add the buttons? In xml you to put the button code in like above or if you are using the graphical layout it is under form widgets and you can just drag and drop and it will add the xml code for you. 

You need to import the buttons in java. You should be able to right click on it and just import it or with Eclipse you can do ctrl shift O and it will do it for you. The code in the strings should look like this `<string name="button1">This button</string>`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If you are what are they? Pretty new to android development myself found it so confusing at first

Comment: It is very confusing. Only started today. I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Can you post your xml and java code in your question so I can see what is going wrong?